# SSRS Setting the color of the data labels in a stacked bar chart

Tags: reporting-services, stacked-chart

I created a stacked bar chart to display ticket counts.  The colors for the chart are dark so I set the color to display the data labels to white. 
When one of the groups has a low number to display, the value is displayed above the chart so it cannot be seen.  That color has to be changed to black.  In addition, when the value is low and the first group, the value cannot be seen well.
Here is an image of the 2 problems:

[image]

The 'Closed' bar has a value of '1' in the first group but it is difficult to see.  I don't know if there is a solution to this.
Is there a way to display this text so that it can be easier to see?

The second issue is that in the 'Open' bar, the top group has a value of 1 but the data label is above the bar so the color will have to be changed to 'Black'.  Is there a way to determine if the value will be displayed above the bar or do I have to play with the values until it is displayed above and then create an expression when the value is below that value, then display data label in Black?

**UPDATE**
What I am trying to do with the values that are too low to see is to add to my current expression for the data label. Currently, I use an `IIF` statement to not show any data labels that are zero and it is working.

```
= IIf(Fields!TicketCnt.Value = 0, "", Fields!TicketCnt.Value)
```

I tried adding of the first condition to not display the label if greater than 0 and less than 6 and the ticket type is 'SPRs'.  This is the code:

```
= IIF((Fields!TicketCnt.Value = 0) OR (Fields!TicketCnt.Value > 0 AND Fields!TicketCnt.Value < 6 AND Fields!TicketType.Value = "SPRs"), "", Fields!TicketCnt.Value)
```

**UPDATE**
I got the code working so the value is not displayed if it is between 1 - 6 and the Board is type SPRs.  I was using TicketType and not Board.

```
= IIF((Fields!TicketCnt.Value = 0) OR (Fields!TicketCnt.Value > 0 AND Fields!TicketCnt.Value < 6 AND Fields!Board.Value = "SPRs"), "", Fields!TicketCnt.Value)
```

Comment: have you checked if there is an option to change the alignment of the text to above the row ?

Comment: I can find no such attribute.  I have read in the documentation that the data label on **stacked** bar charts cannot be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to look on the Smart Labels on properties pane of the chart. You have to click the bar to be able to see the SmartLabels property.

Comment: I click on the Data Labels and select the 'Series label Properties' but there is nothing in that dialog box about text alignment.  There is General, Font, Number, Action, Fill and Border.

Comment: Did you checked the Properties window? If it's hidden on your VS, just click F4 to show it.

Comment: Looking in the Properties Window, there is no Smart Labels property.  This is Report Builder 3.0. What category is it under?

Comment: Try to click one of the value in your chart then check the properties window, there should be smart labels in there. Sort it alphabetically to easily see it.

Comment: There is a 'Position' attribute under 'Appearance' Category.  The definition of the attribute: Specifies the position of the data point label.  I set it to several values (Outside/ Top / Bottom).  It has not affect to the position of the label.  There is another attribute that I use to show/hide labels that are between 0 - 5.  It is in Misc / Label.  I created an expression that correctly shows and hides the label.